# Calling javascript from appended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

Just want to get a concept clear here.

suppose i have this html page:

```
        <script>
        function_1()
           {
          ... posts a form via ajax
           };
        </script>



<body>
<div class='car'>

</div>
</body>
```

On an event I `prepend()` this form (which I get via ajax) to the above `<div class='car'>`

```
<form method='post'>
...
<button type='submit' value='post' />
</form>
```

The idea is to submit this form via ajax by calling the `function_1` function on pressing the submit button.

Does this work? Because when I submit the form it is not calling the `function_1`, its just posting it via regular Http post.

When we `append()` or `prepend()` elements to DOM, do they have access to javascript right away?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending those form elements during run time, so you have to register events for it by using `event-delegation`. And by the way it is a submit button, so whenever you are clicking on it, it will simply invoke its default action, that is submitting the form. So you should use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent its default behaviour or you should need to change the type of that button from `submit` to `button`

Try,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
          function function_1()
           {
              ... posts a form via ajax
           };

          $(document).on("click", "input[type='submit']", function(e) {
               e.preventDefault();

               function_1()
          });
});      
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a delegated event handler, for example:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#your-form-id", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // AJAX code
});
```

Then, the handler will be called on submit regardless of when the form is appended, as long as the form exists.

Comment: Did you call `e.preventDefault()`?

Comment: I was trying to add the code outside $(document).ready() and it wasnt working. And I did not call e.preventDefault() too. still learning, The other answer made it clear. Ill accept that because it is more noob friendly.